# Play a video after every n seconds using mediaelement

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I have a medial element example on jsfiddle which i am using to play a video and have it repeat after every 52 seconds.

This is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/30t50mgc/17/

and the html

```
<video id="youtube1" width="640" height="360" autoplay="true"></video>
```

and the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#youtube1', {
        type: ['video/webm'],
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            var sources = [
                { src: "http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.webm", type: 'video/webm' },
];
            mediaElement.setSrc(sources);
            mediaElement.load();
            mediaElement.play();
        }
    });
}, 52000);
});
```

The video does not play again after 52 seconds which is also the length of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. When playback of a `video` element ends, the `ended` event is raised. You can hook to that event and then start the video playing again by calling `play()`. This has the benefits of being much simpler to code, but also works if the user skips the video ahead/back. With your current method the timer could get out of sync with the video state very easily. Try this:

```js
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#youtube1', {
  type: ['video/webm'],
  success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
    var sources = [{
      src: "http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.webm",
      type: 'video/webm'
    }];
    mediaElement.setSrc(sources);
    mediaElement.load();
    mediaElement.play();

    mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      this.play();
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.13.2/css/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.13.2/js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<video id="youtube1" width="640" height="360" autoplay="true"></video>
```

Comment: I am able to switch the videos like http://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/30t50mgc/20/   but how can i switch to play another video after 5 seconds are over.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code play video every 2 second.

```
    vplayer = new MediaElementPlayer('video');
    // check if paused  

    setInterval(function(){ 
                    var classList = $('.mejs-playpause-button').attr("class").split(' ');
                    for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
                        if (classList[i] === 'mejs-play') {
                           vplayer.play();
                        }
                    }
            },2000);


      // without check paused
      setInterval(function(){ 
         vplayer.play();
     },2000);
```